# The module function returns one character instead of the specified number

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm trying to divide a large code into modules.

Importing the created module. The module looks like this:

```
import random


def password_generator():
    big_alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    small_alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    digits = "0123456789"
    generator = big_alphabet + small_alphabet + digits
    random_password = ''
    for p in range(15):
        random_password += random.choice(generator)
        return random_password


def secret_question_generator():
    digits = "0123456789"
    generator = digits
    random_index = ''
    for i in range(5):
        random_index += random.choice(generator)
        return random_index
```

I call the function from the module as follows: `random_password = generator.password_generator()`

And: `random_index = generator.secret_question_generator()`

But the function returns one character at a time. How to fix the problem? Help please

Comment: why not use [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets look at a minimal example:

```
s = ""
for i in range(10):
  s += "a"
  print(s)
```

And

```
s = ""
for i in range(10):
  s += "a"
print(s)
```

What is the difference between the two? For the first one the print is part of every loop, so you print 10 times.
For the second one it happens after the loop, so it only prints the full string.

But you call the return on the first iteration of the loop every time, which always instantly stops the function and returns a result.

The solution is to have

```
for i in range(14):
  # do your stuff
return (yourvalue)
```

So all 14 iterations run and then you return

Answer (score 1):

You put the return statement inside the for loop. Just unindent it so that the functions only return once the for loop is finished. In your code the loop only happens for i=0 and then it returns the one character that created.

```
for p in range(15):
    random_password += random.choice(generator)
return random_password
```

Also note that

```
return "".join(random.choices(generator, k=15))
```

is an easier and cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Return automatically ends function and in your case returns the string after first iteration. Simply erase indent before return statement:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Put the return statement outside of the for-loop.

```
import random


def password_generator():
    big_alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    small_alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    digits = "0123456789"
    generator = big_alphabet + small_alphabet + digits
    random_password = ''
    for p in range(15):
        random_password += random.choice(generator)
    return random_password


def secret_question_generator():
    digits = "0123456789"
    generator = digits
    random_index = ''
    for i in range(5):
        random_index += random.choice(generator)
    return random_index


print(password_generator())

print(secret_question_generator())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).